# Displaying selected record from a database

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I've got readOne function. This function will read only one record from category table and assign values to name and description variables. It looks like this:

```
require_once('../config/Database.php');

class Category {
    private $conn;
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $description;
    private $created;

public function __construct($db) {
    $this->conn = $db;
}

public function readOne($id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT name, description FROM categories WHERE id = "'.$id.'"'); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    $this->name = $result['name'];
    $this->description = $result['description'];
}
```

and I'm trying to call this using this:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
if ( isset( $_POST['read'], $_POST['id']) ) {

    $cat = new Category($conn);

    $id = filter_input ( INPUT_POST , 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );


    echo $cat->readOne($id);
}}
?>
<div>
<h3>readOne():</h3>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Category id :</label>
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Id"/><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="read" name="read"/><br />
</div>
```

I'm not getting any error, but also nothing happends after I write the category id and press the button, how to fix it?

Connection to the database:

```
<?php

class Database {

public function getConnection() {
    $result = false;
    try {
        $result = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=demo', 'root', '');
    } catch(PDOException $e) { }
    return $result;
}
}
$db = new Database();
$conn = $db->getConnection();
if (!$conn) {
die("Error connecting to the database");
}

?>
```

Comment: You are echoing the return value of readOne, but that has no return statement so it will be null always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your readOne function returns nothing. Change readOne function like this :

```
public function readOne($id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT name, description FROM categories WHERE id = "'.$id.'"'); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    $this->name = $result['name'];
    $this->description = $result['description'];
    return $this->name.$this->description;
}
```

This function return now a string with the name and a description.

Answer (score 1):

your `readOne()` function does not return anything as there is no return statement.
Also please check your `$id` must not be blank.